# Removing some options from select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select option` in my form that has different values each time but is **always 4 options**.

*Here is my code (PS: remember option values, changes for each time)*

```
<select name="selectoption" id="selectoption" selected>
    <option value="2623">option1</option>
    <option value="8982">option2</option>
    <option value="1237">option3</option>
    <option value="9362">option4</option>   
</select>
```

How can I remove the first and second options from my option list?

I have tried with:

```
$("#selectoption option:selected").remove();
```

But it just removes the first option (**option 1**), and I want first 2 options to be removed or in other word, I want to choose which options needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)(aka *lower than*) selector:

```js
$("#selectoption option:lt(2)").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectoption" id="selectoption" selected>
  <option value="2623">option1</option>
  <option value="8982">option2</option>
  <option value="1237">option3</option>
  <option value="9362">option4</option>   
</select>
```

It will remove the option tags with index=2 or lower, therefore the first two elements.

Comment: Or `$("#selectoption option").eq(n).remove();` to remove nth option, if you want more control

Comment: @Mike `eq` would remove only one option each time.

Comment: Yes it will remove only one. But as he said, in case he wants to remove 1st and last option, or say 1st and 3rd, he may find this useful.

Comment: Tnx. Life savior badge ;)